# azure sql service principal admin not authenticating

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have the same issue as here https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/228#issuecomment-506437261

The difference is my service principal is the AD admin of the SQL server. And with no other configuration made prior I cant connect to any of the DBs and get

> "pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")"

BUT if I use the `create user [] from external provider` sql command when I'm the sql server admin my service principal can login at that moment but has insufficient privileges to execute any other command.

And finally if I change back the sql admin back to my service principal now he is able to log in correctly.

How can I get this login access from the start because it is inconvenient to do this every time I want to use service principal as admin on azure sql server?

Comment: did you followed this tutorial [Configure and manage Azure Active Directory authentication with SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure) to configure your  service principal as the AD admin?

Comment: As I explained I have already configured my service principal as AD admin on the azure sql server. BUT it is not possible to authenticate itself and I get "Login failed for user " and I'm using Linux environment to accomplish this step

Comment: I used try to set service principal as the AD admin, but can not access the SQL database. When we set add AD account , such as "***@****.com", it works ok. I can't find any document talk about this.

Comment: did you guys find the solution yet?